# Python 3.4 Comms Stream Delegate - Non-blocking recv and send - data out from asyncio

Tags: multithreading, sockets, queue, nonblocking, python-asyncio

I'm putting together a client server app on RPi.  It has a main thread which creates a comms thread to talk to an iOS device.
The main thread creates an asyncio event loop and a sendQ and a recvQ and passes them as args to the commsDelegate main method in the comms thread.

The trouble I'm having is when iOS device connects, it needs to receive unsolicited data from this Python app as soon as the data becomes available and it needs to be able to send data up to the Python app.  So send and receive need to be non-blocking.

There are great echo server tutorials out there.  But little in terms of the server doing something useful with the data.

Can anyone assist me in getting asyncio to read my send queue and forward data as soon as the main thread has queued it?   I have receive working great.

**Main Thread creates a loop and starts the comms thread:**

```
  commsLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
  commsMainThread = threading.Thread(target=CommsDelegate.commsDelegate, args=(commsInQ,commsOutQ,commsLoop,commsPort,), daemon=True)
  commsMainThread.start()
```

Then asyncio in module CommsDelegate should run the loop as loop.run_forever() server task reading and writing from a socket stream and sending receiving messages using queues back up to the main thread.

Here's my code so far.   I found that if I create a factory for the protocol generator, I can pass it the queue names so the receipt of messages is all good now.  When they arrive from the client they are queued  _nowait and the main thread receives them just fine.

I just need asyncio to handle the queue of outbound messages from the Main thread as they arrive on sendQ, so it can send them on to the connected client.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import asyncio

class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

  def __init__(self, loop, recvQ, sendQ):
    self.loop = loop
    self.recvQ = recvQ
    self.sendQ = sendQ

  def connection_made(self, transport):
    peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
    print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
    self.transport = transport

  def data_received(self, data):
    message = data.decode()
    print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))
    self.recvQ.put_nowait(message.rstrip())

  # Needs work... I think the queue.get_nowait should be a co-ro maybe? 
  def unknownAtTheMo():
    dataToSend = sendQ.get_nowait()
    print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
    self.transport.write(dataToSend)

  # Needs work to close on request from client or server or exc...
  def handleCloseSocket(self):
    print('Close the client socket')
    self.transport.close()

# async co-routine to consume the send message Q from Main Thread
async def consume(sendQ):
  print("In consume coro")
  while True:
    outboundData = await self.sendQ.get()
    print("Consumed", outboundData)
    self.transport.write(outboundData.encode('ascii'))

def commsDelegate(recvQ, sendQ, loop, port):
  asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

  # Connection coroutine - Create a factory to assist the protocol in receipt of the queues as args
  factory = lambda: ProveItServerProtocol(loop, recvQ, sendQ)
  # Each client connection will create a new protocol instance
  connection = loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_server(factory, host='192.168.1.199', port=port))

  # Outgoing message queue handler
  consumer = asyncio.ensure_future(consume(sendQ))

  # Set up connection
  loop.run_until_complete(connection)

  # Wait until the connection is closed
  loop.run_forever()

  # Wait until the queue is empty
  loop.run_until_complete(queue.join())

  # Cancel the consumer
  consumer.cancel()

  # Let the consumer terminate
  loop.run_until_complete(consumer)

  # Close the connection
  connection.close()

  # Close the loop
  loop.close()
```

I send all data messages as json and CommsDelegate performs encode and decode then relays them asis.

Update:  asyncio thread seems to be working well for incoming traffic.  Server receives json and relays it via a queue - non-blocking.

Once the send is working, I'll have a reusable blackbox server on a thread.

Comment: FWIW.  My iOS app is working a treat albeit using CFStreams.  I thought I should move to URLSession-Streamtask but that is so badly documented right now.  Apple docs are all about Command -> Response and not much on handling unsolicited messages.

Comment: I should say that Python does not like the get_event_loop(loop).

Comment: Does the code above work? If not, please add a traceback

Comment: Yes for messages coming in from the comms client.  They are placed on recvQ and my Main thread does a recvQ.get_nowait() resulting in the json coming out for the main thread to process.

Comment: I'm thinking I need a:   async def 'q-consumer' method as an @coroutine   but I'm not very sure yet where that plugs in.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: I need the server loop in CommsDelegate to read the queue (sendQ) passed from Main Thread so it can perform transport.write when messages arrive on that queue.  So the TCP protocol class needs to know what Main thread has queued a message to sendQ.  It has access to the queue.  I know that because, if I add, to the end of the data_received method, a sendQ.get_nowait I get a queued message and I can send that to the client.

Comment: As I understand it, I'm using a factory to create a TCP protocol based server which has 3 pre-determined methods + optional __init__.  connection_made; data_received; connection_lost.  Then I run this in a loop until a close event is triggered and the loop is then stopped.  What I want to do is add a queue_observer method to the class to watch sendQ and, when it sees a message, do:   msg=sendQ.get.nowait() then transport.write(msg)  then sendQ.task_done()

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems with your approach. First, all your clients are using the same `recv` and `send` queues, so there is no way the `consume`  coroutine can know who to reply to.

The second issue has to do with your use of queues as a bridge between the synchronous and the asynchronous worlds. See this part of your code:

```
await self.sendQ.get()
```

If `sendQ` is a regular queue (from the `queue` module), this line will fail because `sendQ` is not a coroutine. On the other hand, if `sendQ` is an `asyncio.Queue`, the main thread won't be able to use `sendQ.put` because it is a coroutine. It would be possible to use `put_nowait`, but thread-safety is not guaranteed in asyncio. Instead, you'd have to use [loop.call_soon_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe):

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(sendQ.put_nowait, message)
```

In general, remember that asyncio is designed to run as the main application. It's supposed to run in the main thread, and communicate with synchronous code through a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (see [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor)).

More information about multithreading in the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading). You might also want to have a look at the [asyncio stream API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) that provides a much nicer interface to work with TCP.

Comment: Thanks a bundle Vincent.  Clears up a few misconceptions I had.

Comment: I really appreciate your assist.  I'm new to python and this really clears up misconceptions I had.  Data hitting the queues is the least of my worries - I could tag the data -  ;-).
I find it amazing how many code examples out there are so over-simplified as to make them kinda pointless.  eg. Echo servers - really?
Interestingly, as an aside, sendQ.get() does work if I code it right after the recvQ.put() but that means it only processes outbound data when data has arrived inbound. 
I'll try the Stream approach - I had to do that on the iOS side so it should work well.  Thanks  ... onward

Comment: I took your advice Vincent and shifted the while shebang into the land of Asyncio coroutines.  No further need for queues or threads or thread-safe considerations.  I'd have rather had a black-box server that I can easily deploy over and over but I do have boilerplate code that I can copy.  A few rough edges needing attention but will be easily sorted.  Cheers